# How can I apply styles online in React with Meteor?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

How can I apply styles online in React with Meteor?

I want to use a local image for the background of a container but my code does not work when invoking the image saved in `images/borealis.jpg` in the `public` folder.

Try this render but it does not work, it could be wrong with the code

```
render() {
        const fondoBorealis = {backgroundImage: 'images/borealis.jpg'};
        return(
            <div className="container-logeo-vitae">
            <div style={{fondoBorealis}} className="logeo-vitae">
                <div className="header wrap">
                    <h1>borealis </h1>
                </div>
                    <div className="form">
                    <center>
                    {this.state.error ? <p>{this.state.error}</p> : undefined}
                        <form className="form-logeo-vitae" onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                            <input className="input-logeo" autoComplete="off" type="email" ref="email" placeholder="correo" />
                            <input className="input-logeo" autoComplete="off" type="password" ref="pass" placeholder="••••••••••" />
                            <button className="btn">login</button>
                        </form>
                    <Link to="/registro" className="link-to">crea una cuenta.</Link>
                    </center>
                    </div>
            </div>  
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: If you add another '/' at the beginning of the path, like so: `/images/borealis.jpg`, also not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, you're so close! It's not a pathing issue but a css issue. When using background image in a css file, it would look like this:

```
background-image: url(/images/borealis.jpg);
```

In what you have now it looks like you just missed the url part. So it will work if you change it to this:

```
const fondoBorealis = {backgroundImage: 'url(/images/borealis.jpg)'};
```

And to use it you would do this (with one set of curly braces. There are two sets in your current code):

```
style={fondoBorealis}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var co_img = "/images/borealis.jpg";
const sheshema = {
  backgroundImage: "url(" + co_img + ")"
}
<div style={sheshema}>
 </div>
```

This should work. try it.